# Typescript type casting not working

Tags: casting, typescript

I am pretty new to TypeScript. I started with a book called Typescript Revealed (Pub Feb.2013). In Chapter 2 there is a section called "Casts" that has the following example:

`var a : int = <int>SomeNumberAsAString;`

I tried to apply the example, as follows:

```
var SomeNumberAsAString = "1000";
var a: int = <int>SomeNumberAsAString;
```

But compiler gave me an error:

> hello.ts(2,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'int'.
>      hello.ts(2,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'int'.

I'm wondering how to do this cast, or has the specification of Typescript changed?

Comment: I'd suggest really parsing it into a number: `var a:number = parseInt(SomeNumberAsAString, 10);`

Comment: @NemanjaMiljkovic Thanks, I will never user thing like this in coding, it is just for learning purpose.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> (Pub Feb.2013)

That book is *old*. Its called `number` now.

```
var SomeNumberAsAString = "1000";
var a: number = <number><any>SomeNumberAsAString;
```

Also this assertion *is very unsafe and I would not do this in production code*. But it gets the point across :)

## More

A more up to date book chapter on assertions :  <del>https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html</del>
https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion

Comment: Thanks, but I still got error like: hello.ts(2,17): error TS2352: Neither type 'string' nor type 'number' is assignable to the other.

Comment: Updated ... you need an `any` in there :)

Comment: See `double assertion` in the chapter I posted 

Comment: Thanks, you wrote this book?

Comment: You should not make that cast at all. `var a:number = Number(someString)` the way to go here.

Comment: @basarat Cool, great job!

Comment: @Nypan Thanks, could you tell me what is the diff between number and Number in typescript?

Comment: @Kuan its the same as `number` vs. `Number` in *JavaScript*. Funnily in JavaScript `Number('string')` returns `number` :)

Comment: Indeed what @Kuan said. Number(string) tries to convert the string to a number se https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number for more info on Number.

Comment: also an option: `let a = parseInt(someString, 10);`.  (You almost always want `let` or `const` instead of `var`. You don't need the `:number` type because TypeScript can figure it out automatically for you in this case, based off of the return type of `parseInt`.)

Comment: Also, if targeting ES5 (feel sorry for you if not) one can drop the `10` base specifier

Comment: It's worth to mention that in js there will be no typecasting at all

let SomeNumberAsAString = "1000";
let a: number = <number><any>SomeNumberAsAString;

console.log(typeof a);

Answer (score 10):

I've read @basarat's answer and decided to post my own since I strongly believe that there's still some room for explanation.

Be warned, `<number><any>` casting won't generate a number. In fact it will allow your code to be compiled (thus you'll pass all static typing checks) but it won't be a number in javascript. Consider this snippet of code:

```
let str = "1000";
let a: number = <number><any>str;
let b: number = parseInt(str); //or just let b = parseInt(str)

console.log(typeof a); // string
console.log(typeof b); // number
```

I hardly can imagine cases when `a`-case is beneficial compared to `b`-case. I'd go with just parseInt or parseFloat or Number, whatever fits more. `<T><any>` casting looks smart but you must be 100% sure what you are supposed to achieve by that idiom.

And in most cases you probably don't want to achieve that )

Answer (score 3):

Here is the **cleanest** way to do it.

```
const numberString = '1000';
const a: int = numberString as any;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this variant

```js
let SomeNumberAsAString = '1000';
let a = +SomeNumberAsAString;
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const a: number = <number> +SomeNumberAsAString;
```

`+SomeNumberAsAString` converts the string value to the number.

`<number>` before `+SomeNumberAsAString` says to Typescript compiler that we need to cast the type of the value to type `number`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.