# TypeScript type casting a string with as operator

Tags: typescript

```
function doSomething(a : any) {
    let b = (a as Array<any>)
    alert(typeof b) // gives "string"
}

doSomething("Hello")
```

The alert shows "string". What I expected was something like a `null`. I haven't found much documentation on the `as` operator. Maybe [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator) is the "official" one.

Here is [a related quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032303/typescript-type-casting-not-working).

Do I still have to check the type of `b` myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as` operator and the other assertion syntax `<T>expr` are identical apart from syntax. Neither cause any runtime behavior at all.

Comment: So I must be careful because there may be a runtime error. I've read the compiled code, it looks just like plain JS that one could have written. Why does not the compiler complain that the cast may fail? (Though actually it can't fail?)

Comment: You said the type was `any` -- there is no cast you could write which would be guaranteed to succeed!

Comment: Yeah that's my...fault. I like Swift's `if let a = b as? TheType {...}`. Thanks!

Comment: So the operator is completely useless and has no runtime impact? Wow. Almost two decades later and JS still hasn't caught up to AS3.
"When a cast fails in ActionScript 3, a TypeError is thrown. With the as operator in ActionScript 3, whenever a cast fails the default value for the datatype is returned."